# Getting Last Uploaded and Previous Year Last Uploaded

Tags: sql, vertica

First time posting. I'm currently getting the `last_uploaded_date` for a given `metric_name` using the OVER() function. I'm also wanting to get the `last_uploaded_date` for `timestamps > 12 months` for a given `metric_name`.

```
    SELECT *,
           MAX(timestamp) OVER (partition by metric_name) as last_uploaded_date
    FROM table
```

How would I go about getting the 
`MAX(timestamp)` for a given `metric_name` `WHERE timestamp > 12 months ago`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT t.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN timestamp < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 year' THEN timestamp END) OVER (partition by metric_name) as last_uploaded_date_minus_1year
FROM table t
```